# Choosing a Portal / CMS software for developing multi brand websites?

Tags: content-management-system, portal

We are in the early stage of overhauling a multi-brand website built using a custom developed java mvc framework to enable web 2.0 features. Built-in features we are looking at are: i18n, sso, content search and indexing, personalization, mashup support, ajax support, rich media content storage and management support, friendly to search engine optimizations, bookmarkable URLs, support for social networking sites, support for page composition and decoration using templates.

A combination of these features are supported by many portal and cms software.

Any insights will be very helpful in using a portal/cms combination to address this requirements!

This is a follow-up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now) focusing on the portal/cms angle

Answer (score 0):

we are developing the same sort of thing, we are using Umbraco, open source, by far the best opensource we have come across

Answer (score 0):

[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html) comes to mind.  The ability to skin and implement templates is a core strength of the product.  You can create channels of content as well as enable varying levels of user customization via roles.

Another nice feature is that you can export your changes to your template.  that way you can port your changes easily from QA to a customer site.

Finally, there is a very active community of [extension developers](http://extensions.joomla.org/) with customizations, as well as numerous template designers.

Answer (score 0):

If you require a Portal that does integrate with your CRM such as Salesforce and yet allows you to build a Mobile-Optimized branded portal for Customers, Partners or any other groups of users you can check out Magentrix:
 [www.magentrix.com](http://www.magentrix.com)